# can you access environment property from java annotation?

Tags: java, properties, annotations, environment

I have an annotation that looks like:

```
@MessageDriven
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1")
public class ProcessingEntitiesQueueListenerMDB implements MessageListener { 
     ......
     ......
     .....
}
```

Is it possible to pass in the value for maxSession from environment variable?
Something like:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "${mdb.maxSessionVal")
```

The parameter mdb.maxSessionVal will be passed in using -Dmdb.maxSessionVal = 10 or something like that.

Is it possible or are they fixed at compile time?

Comment: Annotations are baked into the .class file. There's no way for them to collect anything from the runtime environment.